# Unable to refresh core data and display it in tableview using UIRefreshControl

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, pull-to-refresh, uirefreshcontrol

I am fetching json data from blog and storing it in core data. Now i want to add pull to refresh, so that if there are any updates on the blog, they reflect in the app as well. i found a post with similar problem and it suggested to add this code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to Refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}

func refresh() {
    NSFetchedResultsController.deleteCacheWithName("Master")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    println("refreshed")

       }
```

The problem is neither the coredata nor the tableview is getting updated after puling down to refresh.

The code that fetches and saves json data in core data is as below:

```
func animalSelected(animal: Animal) {

var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var error : NSError?

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(animal.url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    if (error != nil){
        println(error)

    }else{

        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MIBlog")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

        for result in results!
        {
            context.deleteObject(result as NSManagedObject)
            context.save(nil)

        }


        let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var posts = [[String:String]()]

        var post:AnyObject

        var authorDictionary:AnyObject
        var newBlogItem:NSManagedObject
        for var i = 0; i < jsonResult["posts"]!.count; i++
        {
            posts.append([String:String]())
            post = jsonResult["posts"]![i] as NSDictionary
            posts[i]["title"] = post["title"] as? NSString
            posts[i]["publishedDate"] = post["date"] as? NSString
            posts[i]["content"] = post["content"] as? NSString
            authorDictionary = post["author"] as NSDictionary
            posts[i]["author"] = post["name"] as? NSString


            newBlogItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MIBlog", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["title"], forKey: "title")
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["publishedDate"], forKey: "publishedDate")  
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["content"], forKey: "content")
            newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["author"], forKey: "author")

            context.save(nil)

        }
        request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MIBlog")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    }

})

task.resume()

delegate?.collapseSidePanels?()

}
```

**MY fetchResultController Code:**

```
 // MARK: - Fetched results controller

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
        }
        var appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        self.managedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MIBlog", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "publishedDate", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()


}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    case .Move:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
        }

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
           activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
```

I am unable to figure out how should i update the core data while refreshing.

Plsss plss pls help.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a `NSFetchedResultsController` you just need to properly implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods. Then all you have to do is save.

```
context.save(nil)
```

Some remarks:

I think it is not a good idea to save inside the loop. Better save at the end after all the objects are inserted.

It does not make too much sense to delete all and re-insert all again. Instead, you should only change those objects that have changes.

The variable `results` will be discarded when the completion block returns. It is not clear what you want to accomplish with this fetch result.

If you did *not* implement the fetched results controller delegate, you will need to call `performFetch` again, or simply set the fetched results controller to `nil` and let it lazily recreate itself. Then just update the UI which should get the data automatically from the fetched results controller

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I am new to iOS development and the methods i have implemented were suggested in an online course in Udemy. However, do you suggest that i have to just add `context.save(nil)` in my refresh func??

Comment: This is how the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` works. Use the Xcode boilerplate code which you will find when creating a new project and checking "Core Data".

Comment: Yes Sir.. I had checked the Core Data while creating the project. I have updated my question to show the `FetchedResultsController` . I want to know what should be done in the Refresh function so that the core data and tableView both get updated on pull to refresh.

Comment: Look at the answer. `nil` out the FRC and `reloadData()`.